# Redirect for subdomain not working in GoDaddy. CNAME in place, but getting 404

Tags: redirects, subdomain, godaddy, cname

After reading:

- [CNAME for subdomain does not work - 404 Error](https://serverfault.com/questions/80347/cname-for-subdomain-does-not-work-404-error)
- [Redirecting an entire domain to another in one CNAME record [duplicate]](https://serverfault.com/questions/618191/redirecting-an-entire-domain-to-another-in-one-cname-record)

I am facing some problems when trying to redirect a subdomain to another subdomain. Here is the network infrastructure:

- I have a CNAME registred in uolhost.com called *mysubdomain1.mydomain1.com*;
- the CNAME (*mysubdomain1.mydomain1.com*), is pointing to *mysubdomain2.mydomain2.com*, which is hosted by GoDaddy;
- When I use the ping command on *mysubdomain1.mydomain1.com*, I see that the redirection is working just fine, pointing to the IP of *mysubdomain2.mydomain2.com*;
- When I type into my browser *mysubdomain2.mydomain2.com*, the correct site is shown;
- **But when I type *mysubdomain1.mydomain1.com*, I get a 404 error from GoDaddy**;

Seems that they are working with more then one site per host, and the subdomain don't get properly resolved.

GoDaddy suggested to create a 301 redirect, but this will show that the user has been redirected in the browser.

I want any solution that masks the mysubdomain2 as mysubdomain1, is that possible?

Comment: CNAME is an alias and not a redirect.

Comment: The answer is already in the URLs referenced. What kind of environment you have? Plesk shared hosting from GoDaddy?

Comment: Plesk shared hosting from GoDaddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that GoDaddy provides you a virtual host for DNS name `mysubdomain2.mydomain2.com`.

When you try to enter the site with `mysubdomain1.mydomain1.com`, the browser first makes a DNS lookup for the domain name. The lookup results in CNAME record telling to look up IP address for `mysubdomain2.mydomain2.com`, and make the request there.

The web browser doesn't change the virtual host it is requesting based on the result of DNS lookup.

So, what happens here is that your browser opens TCP connection to the GoDaddy web server, and asks for `mysubdomain1.mydomain1.com` from the site. GoDaddy replies with 404, since no such site is there.

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want:

1. Ask GoDaddy to add `mysubdomain2.mydomain2.com` virtualhost to their webserver, pointing to the same directory as `mysubdomain1.mydomain1.com`. I don't know if GoDaddy does these kinds of things, as it is kind of special.
2. Configure a webserver at separate place for `mysubdomain1.mydomain1.com`, and make it reverse proxy requests to GoDaddy's server.